# Adding Google Maps Search Bar with Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Below are all the Javascript functions I am using for my website. Basically the load function is calling and dealing with data from a PHP database, so I have a map being created and worked on from there. However, I am trying to add a search bar to the map, and currently it refreshes the map when selecting a constraint and the search box disappears from the top left corner of the map. The only way it can be seen again is by refreshing the page. It is able to pull up autocomplete suggestions, and puts a marker on said location, and constraints can be chosen that change the map and places more marker on there. But then the search box disappears and the map location also changes within the map when a constraint is picked. Is there anyway to incorporate the search box in the map to put a marker on a specified location, and keep that view on that location there even when data is passed from PHP to put more markers on the map? Should I be combining the load and initialize function? Help would be greatly appreciated from this first time poster!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
  }
};

function load() {

var markers = [];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.166531, -86.528549),
    zoom: 19,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

var passtypevalue = document.forms[0].passes.value;
var distancevalue = document.forms[0].distance.value;
var freevalue = document.forms[0].free.checked;
var metersvalue = document.forms[0].meters.checked;
var garagevalue = document.forms[0].garage.checked;
var campuspassvalue = document.forms[0].campuspass.checked;
var residentpassvalue = document.forms[0].residentpass.checked;

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
downloadUrl("form_action.php", 
function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {if (passtypevalue==markers[i].getAttribute("TypeOfPass") || 
    freevalue==markers[i].getAttribute("Free") || metersvalue==true || garagevalue==true || campuspassvalue==true || residentpassvalue==true){
      var spot = markers[i].getAttribute("SpotID");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("TypeOfPass");
      var free = markers[i].getAttribute("Free");
      var meter = markers[i].getAttribute("Meter");
      var garage = markers[i].getAttribute("Garage");
      var resident = markers[i].getAttribute("ResidentPass");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Latitude")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Longitude")));
      var html = "<b>" + spot + "</b> <br/>" + type;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
      }}
    });
```

}

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', 
function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```

}

```
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
    }
};

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}
 up206b.initialize = function()
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.070264, -118.4440562);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
    }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(center);
```

});

```
function doNothing() {}

<script>
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
  document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

if (places.length == 0) {
  return;
}
for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
  marker.setMap(null);
}

// For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
markers = [];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
  var image = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

  // Create a marker for each place.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

});

```
  // [END region_getplaces]
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
```

});
}

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Comment: I feel that I am not being clear enough, but I just want to be able to keep the positioning of the map fixed onto a custom searched location without it changing the map view when someone picks parameters (i.e. meters, garages, etc.)

Comment: Bumping, I could really use some help. All I want to know is if its possible to incorporate the search bar's location with jquery producing marks on my map is possible

Comment: Please check out [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCqIPbu1the6Nrm3Rgic?p=preview), you can get some idea of `Google Maps Search Bar with Autocomplete` in `javascript`.